# React - Date displays in two different ways

Tags: reactjs

I have to components, and they display dates in different ways so I don't really understand what's going on with them?

```
import React from 'react'
import { useForm, useStep } from "react-hooks-helper";
import FlatAddress from './FlatAddress';
import FlatInfo from './FlatInfo';
import FlatChecklist from './FlatChecklist'

const defaultData = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    birthday: new Date(),
    address: {
        street: '',
        suburb: '',
        city: '',
        country: '',
    },
}

const steps = [
    {id: "information"},
    {id: "address"},
    {id: "photo"}
]

const Flat = (props) => {
    const {user} = props;
    const [formData, setForm] = useForm(defaultData);
    const {step, navigation} = useStep({
        steps,
        initialStep: 0,
    })
    const prop = {formData, setForm, navigation};

    switch(step.id){
        case "information":
            return <FlatInfo {...prop} user = {user} updateUser = {props.updateUser}/>
        case "address":
            return <FlatAddress {...prop} user = {user} updateUser = {props.updateUser}/>
        case "photo": 
            return <FlatChecklist {...prop} user = {user} updateUser = {props.updateUser}/>
    }

    return(
        <h1>Flat Sign Up</h1>
    )
}

export default Flat
```

This is my second component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { useState } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import DatePicker from 'react-date-picker';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';


const FlatInfo = (props) => {
    //Pass the navigation from the parent
    const {navigation} = props;
    //Deconstruct the form details
    const {firstName, lastName, birthday} = props.formData;

    const [dob, setDOB] = useState(new Date());
    const setBirthday = () => {
      console.log(birthday);
      console.log(dob);
    }

    //Declare errors
    const [error, setError] = useState({});
    const findError = () => {
      const errorFound = {};

      if(!firstName.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)){
        errorFound.firstName = "First name should contain letters only.";
      }

      if(!lastName.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)){
        errorFound.lastName = "Last name should contain letters only.";
      }

      if(dob.getFullYear() < 1921){
        errorFound.dob = "Too old";
      } else if (dob.getFullYear() > 2007){
        errorFound.dob = "This app is for 15+";
      }
      
      return errorFound;
    }

    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Check if all the inputs are valid
        const newError = findError();
        console.log(newError);

        //Proceed to the next step if inputs are valid
        if(Object.keys(newError).length > 0){
          //Found errors and set the errors to the useState
          setError(newError);
        }else{
          navigation.next();
          setBirthday();
          //Update the user details
          props.updateUser({['firstName']:firstName});
          props.updateUser({['lastName']:lastName});
          props.updateUser({['DOB']: dob});
        }
    }

    return (
        <form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <h1>This is flat info page</h1>

        <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            variant="outlined"
            label="First Name"
            name="firstName"
            value={firstName}
            onChange={props.setForm}
            placeholder = "Enter your first name...."
            margin="normal"
            variant="standard"
            autoComplete="off"
        /> 
        <br />
        {error.firstName && <div style = {{color: "red"}}>{error.firstName}</div>}

        <TextField
            id="outlined-basic"
            variant="outlined"
            label="Last Name"
            name="lastName"
            value={lastName}
            onChange={props.setForm}
            placeholder = "Enter your last name...."
            margin="normal"
            variant="standard"
            autoComplete="off"
        />
        <br />
        {error.lastName && <div style = {{color: "red"}}>{error.lastName}</div>}

        <InputLabel> D.O.B </InputLabel>
        <DatePicker
        label = "D.O.B"
        onChange={setDOB}
        value={dob}
        />
        {error.dob && <div style = {{color: "red"}}>{error.dob}</div>}

        <br />
        <br />


        <Button variant="contained"
        onClick = {() => props.history.push('/')}>Back</Button>
        <Button variant="contained"
        color = "secondary" 
        type="submit">Next</Button>
        </form>
    )
}

 export default withRouter(FlatInfo);
```

When I console.log, the birthday shows this format: **2021-08-29T05:00:52.208Z**, while the dob has this format: *Wed Aug 10 2005 00:00:00 GMT+1200 (NZST)*

How do I assign the DOB value into the birthday?

Comment: My guess is you would use the passed `setForm` prop to update the form data. Where are you wanting to do this assignment, the `setBirthday` function?

Comment: I tried using the setForm to update it but nothing happened. I also tried to access the year from birthday by using birthday.getFullYear() and it returns and undefined value so I don't know if it has something to do with the format?

Comment: Sure, the timezone is different, one is UTC, the other is UTC+12, and yeah the string format is different. Javascript date objects are notoriously difficult to work with. You may just need to shift the zone offset. Ot use a dataTime library (Luxon, Moment, etc..) that makes working with DateTime objects easier.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm super new to React and Javascipt ( I have a little bit experience with Java but it seems irrelevant here), can you elaborate that?

Comment: Are you trying to update the `birthday` field of your form data to be the `dob` state value in `FlatInfo` component, and if so, where are you trying to do this? Is your issue the updating of form fields/state, or the data format?

Comment: FWIW if you are trying to update the form state then it may be beneficial to update your question to include all the relevant code. Can you share also the custom hooks? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As your new , if starting using moment library, it will be easy for most of the cases it will reduce the development time and bugs https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment

Comment: @DrewReese I'm trying to set the value "birthday" in my Flat as the "dob" in FlatInfo. In FlatInfo tried changing the const birthday to `let {birthday} = props.formData` and then assigning  `birthday = dob` and then uses `props.setForm` to update the form in the `Flat` component

Comment: `birthday` is likely part of some other state (from the `useForm` hook I asked you to share) and `dob` is local state. It looks like you are trying to mutate them instead of enqueuing an update.

Comment: This is the useForm hook: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hooks-helper

Comment: I see. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox that we can inspect and live debug in?